# How to display only Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a list of beers, which is my main activity **MainActivity**. Whenever I click in one of them, I want to display a new screen showing the beer info.

This is how my list looks and the code that is executed to create my fragment.

[image]

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // Data to send to fragment
        Beer beer = displayedList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("Beer", beer);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("BeerList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) beerList);

        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
        BeerInfoFragment beerInfoFragment = new BeerInfoFragment();
        beerInfoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, beerInfoFragment);
        // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
        // Complete the changes added above
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

However, instead of displaying the beer's info on a new screen, I got both layouts at the same time:

[image]

**QUESTION:** How can I make to just display the Fragment Layout instead of both?

This is how my MainActivity layout looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you need two fragments , first one to display list and second you already have

Comment: Have you tried to add a background color to your fragment layout?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I'll search about that
AlbertoMéndez I still can scroll using the list scrollbar I'd rather just display one layout even if I could hide MainActivity layout

Comment: No, you add a touch listener to your fragment (and long touch listener), and then you are done. If you only want one of them I think you need to change your approach

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez ok, I see what you mean. I actually want both because I want it to work on a tablet (displaying list and the info of the selected beer at the same time), so I guess your approach is the right one. So, as you say, can I both at the same time but just one working and being "displayed" because there is no more space?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two fragments.

1. **BeerListFragment**: this fragment will have the recyclerview to display the list of beers you have.
2. **BeerInfoFragment**: This fragment will display the detail of the beer item clicked / selected.

Now, on Launch of your MainActivity add the BeerListFragment to the container. Capture the click of the item and after processing it open the BeerInfoFragment as you have mentioned in the question.